# Анимация фона в FireFox

Tags: html, css

```css
.backwrap {
    background: #113243; 
    background-size:100% 100%;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:1;
}

/* Shapes & Animation
*/

.epic-icon {
    font-size:210%!important;
    opacity:0.5;
    display:inline-block;
    width:35px;
    height:35px;
    text-align:center;
    transition:0.3s all;
}

.back-shapes {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.back-shapes img {
    opacity:0.2;
    position:absolute;
    width:2%;
}

.back-shapes em {
    opacity:0.2;
    position:absolute;
    width:2%;
    font-size:240%!important;
    color:#fff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1400px) {
    .back-shapes img {
        width:3%;
    }
    .back-shapes em {
        font-size:260%!important;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .back-shapes img {
        width:4%;
    }
    .back-shapes em {
        font-size:230%!important;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .back-shapes img {
        width:5%;
    }
    .back-shapes em {
        font-size:180%!important;
    }
}

.floating{animation-name:floating;-webkit-animation-name:floating;-moz-animation-name:floating;animation-duration:5s;-webkit-animation-duration:5s;-moz-animation-duration:5s;animation-iteration-count:infinite;-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;-moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;}
@keyframes floating{0%{transform:translateY(0%) rotate(-55deg);}
50%{transform:translateY(300%) rotate(55deg);}
100%{transform:translateY(0%) rotate(-55deg);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes floating{0%{-webkit-transform:translateY(0%);}
50%{-webkit-transform:translateY(300%);}
100%{-webkit-transform:translateY(0%);}
}
@-moz-keyframes floating{0%{-moz-transform:translateY(0%);}
50%{-moz-transform:translateY(300%);}
100%{-moz-transform:translateY(0%);}
}

/* Bootstrap's Grid
*/

.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12{position: relative;min-height: 1px;padding-right: 15px;padding-left: 15px;}
.col-xs-1, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12{float: left;}
.col-xs-12{width: 100%;}
.col-xs-11{width: 91.66666667%;}
.col-xs-10{width: 83.33333333%;}
.col-xs-9{width: 75%;}
.col-xs-8{width: 66.66666667%;}
.col-xs-7{width: 58.33333333%;}
.col-xs-6{width: 50%;}
.col-xs-5{width: 41.66666667%;}
.col-xs-4{width: 33.33333333%;}
.col-xs-3{width: 25%;}
.col-xs-2{width: 16.66666667%;}
.col-xs-1{width: 8.33333333%;}
.col-xs-pull-12{right: 100%;}
.col-xs-pull-11{right: 91.66666667%;}
.col-xs-pull-10{right: 83.33333333%;}
.col-xs-pull-9{right: 75%;}
.col-xs-pull-8{right: 66.66666667%;}
.col-xs-pull-7{right: 58.33333333%;}
.col-xs-pull-6{right: 50%;}
.col-xs-pull-5{right: 41.66666667%;}
.col-xs-pull-4{right: 33.33333333%;}
.col-xs-pull-3{right: 25%;}
.col-xs-pull-2{right: 16.66666667%;}
.col-xs-pull-1{right: 8.33333333%;}
.col-xs-pull-0{right: auto;}
.col-xs-push-12{left: 100%;}
.col-xs-push-11{left: 91.66666667%;}
.col-xs-push-10{left: 83.33333333%;}
.col-xs-push-9{left: 75%;}
.col-xs-push-8{left: 66.66666667%;}
.col-xs-push-7{left: 58.33333333%;}
.col-xs-push-6{left: 50%;}
.col-xs-push-5{left: 41.66666667%;}
.col-xs-push-4{left: 33.33333333%;}
.col-xs-push-3{left: 25%;}
.col-xs-push-2{left: 16.66666667%;}
.col-xs-push-1{left: 8.33333333%;}
.col-xs-push-0{left: auto;}
.col-xs-offset-12{margin-left: 100%;}
.col-xs-offset-11{margin-left: 91.66666667%;}
.col-xs-offset-10{margin-left: 83.33333333%;}
.col-xs-offset-9{margin-left: 75%;}
.col-xs-offset-8{margin-left: 66.66666667%;}
.col-xs-offset-7{margin-left: 58.33333333%;}
.col-xs-offset-6{margin-left: 50%;}
.col-xs-offset-5{margin-left: 41.66666667%;}
.col-xs-offset-4{margin-left: 33.33333333%;}
.col-xs-offset-3{margin-left: 25%;}
.col-xs-offset-2{margin-left: 16.66666667%;}
.col-xs-offset-1{margin-left: 8.33333333%;}
.col-xs-offset-0{margin-left: 0;}
@media (min-width:768px){.col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12{float: left;}
.col-sm-12{width: 100%;}
.col-sm-11{width: 91.66666667%;}
.col-sm-10{width: 83.33333333%;}
.col-sm-9{width: 75%;}
.col-sm-8{width: 66.66666667%;}
.col-sm-7{width: 58.33333333%;}
.col-sm-6{width: 50%;}
.col-sm-5{width: 41.66666667%;}
.col-sm-4{width: 33.33333333%;}
.col-sm-3{width: 25%;}
.col-sm-2{width: 16.66666667%;}
.col-sm-1{width: 8.33333333%;}
.col-sm-pull-12{right: 100%;}
.col-sm-pull-11{right: 91.66666667%;}
.col-sm-pull-10{right: 83.33333333%;}
.col-sm-pull-9{right: 75%;}
.col-sm-pull-8{right: 66.66666667%;}
.col-sm-pull-7{right: 58.33333333%;}
.col-sm-pull-6{right: 50%;}
.col-sm-pull-5{right: 41.66666667%;}
.col-sm-pull-4{right: 33.33333333%;}
.col-sm-pull-3{right: 25%;}
.col-sm-pull-2{right: 16.66666667%;}
.col-sm-pull-1{right: 8.33333333%;}
.col-sm-pull-0{right: auto;}
.col-sm-push-12{left: 100%;}
.col-sm-push-11{left: 91.66666667%;}
.col-sm-push-10{left: 83.33333333%;}
.col-sm-push-9{left: 75%;}
.col-sm-push-8{left: 66.66666667%;}
.col-sm-push-7{left: 58.33333333%;}
.col-sm-push-6{left: 50%;}
.col-sm-push-5{left: 41.66666667%;}
.col-sm-push-4{left: 33.33333333%;}
.col-sm-push-3{left: 25%;}
.col-sm-push-2{left: 16.66666667%;}
.col-sm-push-1{left: 8.33333333%;}
.col-sm-push-0{left: auto;}
.col-sm-offset-12{margin-left: 100%;}
.col-sm-offset-11{margin-left: 91.66666667%;}
.col-sm-offset-10{margin-left: 83.33333333%;}
.col-sm-offset-9{margin-left: 75%;}
.col-sm-offset-8{margin-left: 66.66666667%;}
.col-sm-offset-7{margin-left: 58.33333333%;}
.col-sm-offset-6{margin-left: 50%;}
.col-sm-offset-5{margin-left: 41.66666667%;}
.col-sm-offset-4{margin-left: 33.33333333%;}
.col-sm-offset-3{margin-left: 25%;}
.col-sm-offset-2{margin-left: 16.66666667%;}
.col-sm-offset-1{margin-left: 8.33333333%;}
.col-sm-offset-0{margin-left: 0;}
}
@media (min-width:992px){.col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12{float: left;}
.col-md-12{width: 100%;}
.col-md-11{width: 91.66666667%;}
.col-md-10{width: 83.33333333%;}
.col-md-9{width: 75%;}
.col-md-8{width: 66.66666667%;}
.col-md-7{width: 58.33333333%;}
.col-md-6{width: 50%;}
.col-md-5{width: 41.66666667%;}
.col-md-4{width: 33.33333333%;}
.col-md-3{width: 25%;}
.col-md-2{width: 16.66666667%;}
.col-md-1{width: 8.33333333%;}
.col-md-pull-12{right: 100%;}
.col-md-pull-11{right: 91.66666667%;}
.col-md-pull-10{right: 83.33333333%;}
.col-md-pull-9{right: 75%;}
.col-md-pull-8{right: 66.66666667%;}
.col-md-pull-7{right: 58.33333333%;}
.col-md-pull-6{right: 50%;}
.col-md-pull-5{right: 41.66666667%;}
.col-md-pull-4{right: 33.33333333%;}
.col-md-pull-3{right: 25%;}
.col-md-pull-2{right: 16.66666667%;}
.col-md-pull-1{right: 8.33333333%;}
.col-md-pull-0{right: auto;}
.col-md-push-12{left: 100%;}
.col-md-push-11{left: 91.66666667%;}
.col-md-push-10{left: 83.33333333%;}
.col-md-push-9{left: 75%;}
.col-md-push-8{left: 66.66666667%;}
.col-md-push-7{left: 58.33333333%;}
.col-md-push-6{left: 50%;}
.col-md-push-5{left: 41.66666667%;}
.col-md-push-4{left: 33.33333333%;}
.col-md-push-3{left: 25%;}
.col-md-push-2{left: 16.66666667%;}
.col-md-push-1{left: 8.33333333%;}
.col-md-push-0{left: auto;}
.col-md-offset-12{margin-left: 100%;}
.col-md-offset-11{margin-left: 91.66666667%;}
.col-md-offset-10{margin-left: 83.33333333%;}
.col-md-offset-9{margin-left: 75%;}
.col-md-offset-8{margin-left: 66.66666667%;}
.col-md-offset-7{margin-left: 58.33333333%;}
.col-md-offset-6{margin-left: 50%;}
.col-md-offset-5{margin-left: 41.66666667%;}
.col-md-offset-4{margin-left: 33.33333333%;}
.col-md-offset-3{margin-left: 25%;}
.col-md-offset-2{margin-left: 16.66666667%;}
.col-md-offset-1{margin-left: 8.33333333%;}
.col-md-offset-0{margin-left: 0;}
}
@media (min-width:1200px){.col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12{float: left;}
.col-lg-12{width: 100%;}
.col-lg-11{width: 91.66666667%;}
.col-lg-10{width: 83.33333333%;}
.col-lg-9{width: 75%;}
.col-lg-8{width: 66.66666667%;}
.col-lg-7{width: 58.33333333%;}
.col-lg-6{width: 50%;}
.col-lg-5{width: 41.66666667%;}
.col-lg-4{width: 33.33333333%;}
.col-lg-3{width: 25%;}
.col-lg-2{width: 16.66666667%;}
.col-lg-1{width: 8.33333333%;}
.col-lg-pull-12{right: 100%;}
.col-lg-pull-11{right: 91.66666667%;}
.col-lg-pull-10{right: 83.33333333%;}
.col-lg-pull-9{right: 75%;}
.col-lg-pull-8{right: 66.66666667%;}
.col-lg-pull-7{right: 58.33333333%;}
.col-lg-pull-6{right: 50%;}
.col-lg-pull-5{right: 41.66666667%;}
.col-lg-pull-4{right: 33.33333333%;}
.col-lg-pull-3{right: 25%;}
.col-lg-pull-2{right: 16.66666667%;}
.col-lg-pull-1{right: 8.33333333%;}
.col-lg-pull-0{right: auto;}
.col-lg-push-12{left: 100%;}
.col-lg-push-11{left: 91.66666667%;}
.col-lg-push-10{left: 83.33333333%;}
.col-lg-push-9{left: 75%;}
.col-lg-push-8{left: 66.66666667%;}
.col-lg-push-7{left: 58.33333333%;}
.col-lg-push-6{left: 50%;}
.col-lg-push-5{left: 41.66666667%;}
.col-lg-push-4{left: 33.33333333%;}
.col-lg-push-3{left: 25%;}
.col-lg-push-2{left: 16.66666667%;}
.col-lg-push-1{left: 8.33333333%;}
.col-lg-push-0{left: auto;}
.col-lg-offset-12{margin-left: 100%;}
.col-lg-offset-11{margin-left: 91.66666667%;}
.col-lg-offset-10{margin-left: 83.33333333%;}
.col-lg-offset-9{margin-left: 75%;}
.col-lg-offset-8{margin-left: 66.66666667%;}
.col-lg-offset-7{margin-left: 58.33333333%;}
.col-lg-offset-6{margin-left: 50%;}
.col-lg-offset-5{margin-left: 41.66666667%;}
.col-lg-offset-4{margin-left: 33.33333333%;}
.col-lg-offset-3{margin-left: 25%;}
.col-lg-offset-2{margin-left: 16.66666667%;}
.col-lg-offset-1{margin-left: 8.33333333%;}
.col-lg-offset-0{margin-left: 0;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/cc7ee97be0.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="backwrap gradient">
    <div class="back-shapes">
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-desktop floating" style="top:65.50308008213553%;left:12.239583333333334%;animation-delay:-1.95s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-desktop floating" style="top:7.8028747433264884%;left:5.260416666666667%;animation-delay:-1.6s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-desktop floating" style="top:14.476386036960985%;left:33.4375%;animation-delay:-1.1s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-desktop floating" style="top:39.73305954825462%;left:22.916666666666668%;animation-delay:-4.7s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-eraser floating" style="top:46.50924024640657%;left:64.0625%;animation-delay:-1.5s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-eraser floating" style="top:73.40862422997947%;left:37.708333333333336%;animation-delay:-0.7s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-eraser floating" style="top:34.496919917864474%;left:42.447916666666664%;animation-delay:-0.05s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-git-square floating" style="top:5.030800821355236%;left:17.1875%;animation-delay:-0.45s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-git-square floating" style="top:59.034907597535934%;left:36.458333333333336%;animation-delay:-4.5s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-git-square floating" style="top:8.521560574948666%;left:47.604166666666664%;animation-delay:-3.5s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-linux floating" style="top:40.24640657084189%;left:9.166666666666666%;animation-delay:-0.05s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-linux floating" style="top:76.28336755646818%;left:23.125%;animation-delay:-4.6s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-linux floating" style="top:21.971252566735114%;left:69.73958333333333%;animation-delay:-4.2s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-linux floating" style="top:21.86858316221766%;left:44.375%;animation-delay:-3.05s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-linux floating" style="top:25.15400410677618%;left:27.03125%;animation-delay:-2.7s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-linux floating" style="top:82.95687885010267%;left:51.71875%;animation-delay:-2.1s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-smile-o floating" style="top:68.17248459958932%;left:79.32291666666667%;animation-delay:-3.25s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-smile-o floating" style="top:15.40041067761807%;left:96.04166666666667%;animation-delay:-2.6s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-smile-o floating" style="top:11.396303901437372%;left:79.94791666666667%;animation-delay:-2.15s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-smile-o floating" style="top:10.574948665297741%;left:62.447916666666664%;animation-delay:-1.8s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-whatsapp floating" style="top:75.77002053388091%;left:31.145833333333332%;animation-delay:-3.95s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-whatsapp floating" style="top:27.82340862422998%;left:11.25%;animation-delay:-3.45s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-whatsapp floating" style="top:82.95687885010267%;left:3.9583333333333335%;animation-delay:-2.5s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-whatsapp floating" style="top:11.60164271047228%;left:29.635416666666668%;animation-delay:-2.05s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-whatsapp floating" style="top:26.078028747433265%;left:0.46875%;animation-delay:-1.5s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-whatsapp floating" style="top:49.07597535934291%;left:55.520833333333336%;animation-delay:-1.2s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-whatsapp floating" style="top:71.66324435318275%;left:49.114583333333336%;animation-delay:-0.95s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-whatsapp floating" style="top:41.37577002053388%;left:33.072916666666664%;animation-delay:-0.7s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-wifi floating" style="top:84.49691991786447%;left:19.166666666666668%;animation-delay:-1.65s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-wifi floating" style="top:44.558521560574945%;left:2.65625%;animation-delay:-1.15s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-wifi floating" style="top:51.74537987679671%;left:21.197916666666668%;animation-delay:-0.7s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-wifi floating" style="top:17.864476386036962%;left:57.65625%;animation-delay:-0.45s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-wifi floating" style="top:5.749486652977413%;left:34.583333333333336%;animation-delay:-0.15s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-wifi floating" style="top:66.0164271047228%;left:51.979166666666664%;animation-delay:-4.8s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-wifi floating" style="top:79.67145790554414%;left:76.61458333333333%;animation-delay:-4.5s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-wifi floating" style="top:39.52772073921971%;left:77.34375%;animation-delay:-4.25s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-wifi floating" style="top:29.363449691991786%;left:66.92708333333333%;animation-delay:-4.05s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-wifi floating" style="top:3.2854209445585214%;left:79.375%;animation-delay:-3.8s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-wifi floating" style="top:12.833675564681725%;left:51.666666666666664%;animation-delay:-3.55s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-wifi floating" style="top:34.90759753593429%;left:50.104166666666664%;animation-delay:-3.25s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-user floating" style="top:33.880903490759756%;left:17.552083333333332%;animation-delay:-1.65s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-user floating" style="top:20.32854209445585%;left:17.291666666666668%;animation-delay:-1.25s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-user floating" style="top:24.94866529774127%;left:42.291666666666664%;animation-delay:-0.85s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-user floating" style="top:28.33675564681725%;left:63.75%;animation-delay:-0.5s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-user floating" style="top:42.813141683778234%;left:61.197916666666664%;animation-delay:-0.2s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-user floating" style="top:62.62833675564682%;left:59.53125%;animation-delay:-4.95s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-user floating" style="top:71.66324435318275%;left:59.635416666666664%;animation-delay:-4.6s;"></em>
        <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-user floating" style="top:55.441478439425055%;left:39.84375%;animation-delay:-4.3s;"></em>
    </div>
</div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>




</body>
</html>
```

Нашёл на просторах интернета одну интересную задумку с фоном, довёл её до ума, но наткнулся на одну проблему с которой бьюсь уже день... Проблема в том что в Chrome анимация работает как надо, но в FireFox не полностью (не вращаются иконки)
Прошу помочь или объясните что делаю не так)

Comment: keyframes для moz не прописан. вместо этого 2 раза webkit

Comment: Пробовал, результата нет

Comment: помимо этого нужно и внутри keyframes дописать префиксы

Comment: И это дописывал, сейчас выложу исходник где есть все префиксы

Comment: Обновил код со всеми префиксами, проблема осталась

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас в `keyframes` для `-moz-` и `-webkit-` не прописана анимация вращения, вот они и не вращаются.

```css
.backwrap {
  background: #113243;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Shapes & Animation
*/

.epic-icon {
  font-size: 210%!important;
  opacity: 0.5;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.3s all;
}

.back-shapes {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.back-shapes img {
  opacity: 0.2;
  position: absolute;
  width: 2%;
}

.back-shapes em {
  opacity: 0.2;
  position: absolute;
  width: 2%;
  font-size: 240%!important;
  color: #fff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1400px) {
  .back-shapes img {
    width: 3%;
  }
  .back-shapes em {
    font-size: 260%!important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .back-shapes img {
    width: 4%;
  }
  .back-shapes em {
    font-size: 230%!important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .back-shapes img {
    width: 5%;
  }
  .back-shapes em {
    font-size: 180%!important;
  }
}

.floating {
  animation-name: floating;
  -webkit-animation-name: floating;
  -moz-animation-name: floating;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes floating {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0%) rotate(-55deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(300%) rotate(55deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0%) rotate(-55deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes floating {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%) rotate(-55deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(300%) rotate(55deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%) rotate(-55deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes floating {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0%) rotate(-55deg);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(300%) rotate(55deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: transform: translateY(0%) rotate(-55deg);
  }
}


/* Bootstrap's Grid
*/

.col-xs-1,
.col-sm-1,
.col-md-1,
.col-lg-1,
.col-xs-2,
.col-sm-2,
.col-md-2,
.col-lg-2,
.col-xs-3,
.col-sm-3,
.col-md-3,
.col-lg-3,
.col-xs-4,
.col-sm-4,
.col-md-4,
.col-lg-4,
.col-xs-5,
.col-sm-5,
.col-md-5,
.col-lg-5,
.col-xs-6,
.col-sm-6,
.col-md-6,
.col-lg-6,
.col-xs-7,
.col-sm-7,
.col-md-7,
.col-lg-7,
.col-xs-8,
.col-sm-8,
.col-md-8,
.col-lg-8,
.col-xs-9,
.col-sm-9,
.col-md-9,
.col-lg-9,
.col-xs-10,
.col-sm-10,
.col-md-10,
.col-lg-10,
.col-xs-11,
.col-sm-11,
.col-md-11,
.col-lg-11,
.col-xs-12,
.col-sm-12,
.col-md-12,
.col-lg-12 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.col-xs-1,
.col-xs-2,
.col-xs-3,
.col-xs-4,
.col-xs-5,
.col-xs-6,
.col-xs-7,
.col-xs-8,
.col-xs-9,
.col-xs-10,
.col-xs-11,
.col-xs-12 {
  float: left;
}

.col-xs-12 {
  width: 100%;
}

.col-xs-11 {
  width: 91.66666667%;
}

.col-xs-10 {
  width: 83.33333333%;
}

.col-xs-9 {
  width: 75%;
}

.col-xs-8 {
  width: 66.66666667%;
}

.col-xs-7 {
  width: 58.33333333%;
}

.col-xs-6 {
  width: 50%;
}

.col-xs-5 {
  width: 41.66666667%;
}

.col-xs-4 {
  width: 33.33333333%;
}

.col-xs-3 {
  width: 25%;
}

.col-xs-2 {
  width: 16.66666667%;
}

.col-xs-1 {
  width: 8.33333333%;
}

.col-xs-pull-12 {
  right: 100%;
}

.col-xs-pull-11 {
  right: 91.66666667%;
}

.col-xs-pull-10 {
  right: 83.33333333%;
}

.col-xs-pull-9 {
  right: 75%;
}

.col-xs-pull-8 {
  right: 66.66666667%;
}

.col-xs-pull-7 {
  right: 58.33333333%;
}

.col-xs-pull-6 {
  right: 50%;
}

.col-xs-pull-5 {
  right: 41.66666667%;
}

.col-xs-pull-4 {
  right: 33.33333333%;
}

.col-xs-pull-3 {
  right: 25%;
}

.col-xs-pull-2 {
  right: 16.66666667%;
}

.col-xs-pull-1 {
  right: 8.33333333%;
}

.col-xs-pull-0 {
  right: auto;
}

.col-xs-push-12 {
  left: 100%;
}

.col-xs-push-11 {
  left: 91.66666667%;
}

.col-xs-push-10 {
  left: 83.33333333%;
}

.col-xs-push-9 {
  left: 75%;
}

.col-xs-push-8 {
  left: 66.66666667%;
}

.col-xs-push-7 {
  left: 58.33333333%;
}

.col-xs-push-6 {
  left: 50%;
}

.col-xs-push-5 {
  left: 41.66666667%;
}

.col-xs-push-4 {
  left: 33.33333333%;
}

.col-xs-push-3 {
  left: 25%;
}

.col-xs-push-2 {
  left: 16.66666667%;
}

.col-xs-push-1 {
  left: 8.33333333%;
}

.col-xs-push-0 {
  left: auto;
}

.col-xs-offset-12 {
  margin-left: 100%;
}

.col-xs-offset-11 {
  margin-left: 91.66666667%;
}

.col-xs-offset-10 {
  margin-left: 83.33333333%;
}

.col-xs-offset-9 {
  margin-left: 75%;
}

.col-xs-offset-8 {
  margin-left: 66.66666667%;
}

.col-xs-offset-7 {
  margin-left: 58.33333333%;
}

.col-xs-offset-6 {
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.col-xs-offset-5 {
  margin-left: 41.66666667%;
}

.col-xs-offset-4 {
  margin-left: 33.33333333%;
}

.col-xs-offset-3 {
  margin-left: 25%;
}

.col-xs-offset-2 {
  margin-left: 16.66666667%;
}

.col-xs-offset-1 {
  margin-left: 8.33333333%;
}

.col-xs-offset-0 {
  margin-left: 0;
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .col-sm-1,
  .col-sm-2,
  .col-sm-3,
  .col-sm-4,
  .col-sm-5,
  .col-sm-6,
  .col-sm-7,
  .col-sm-8,
  .col-sm-9,
  .col-sm-10,
  .col-sm-11,
  .col-sm-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-sm-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-sm-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-12 {
    right: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-11 {
    right: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-10 {
    right: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-9 {
    right: 75%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-8 {
    right: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-7 {
    right: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-6 {
    right: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-5 {
    right: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-4 {
    right: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-3 {
    right: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-2 {
    right: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-1 {
    right: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-0 {
    right: auto;
  }
  .col-sm-push-12 {
    left: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-11 {
    left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-10 {
    left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-9 {
    left: 75%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-8 {
    left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-7 {
    left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-6 {
    left: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-5 {
    left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-4 {
    left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-3 {
    left: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-2 {
    left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-1 {
    left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-0 {
    left: auto;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-12 {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-11 {
    margin-left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-10 {
    margin-left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-9 {
    margin-left: 75%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-8 {
    margin-left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-7 {
    margin-left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-6 {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-5 {
    margin-left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-4 {
    margin-left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-3 {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-1 {
    margin-left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-0 {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
  .col-md-1,
  .col-md-2,
  .col-md-3,
  .col-md-4,
  .col-md-5,
  .col-md-6,
  .col-md-7,
  .col-md-8,
  .col-md-9,
  .col-md-10,
  .col-md-11,
  .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-12 {
    right: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-11 {
    right: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-10 {
    right: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-9 {
    right: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-8 {
    right: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-7 {
    right: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-6 {
    right: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-5 {
    right: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-4 {
    right: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-3 {
    right: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-2 {
    right: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-1 {
    right: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-0 {
    right: auto;
  }
  .col-md-push-12 {
    left: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-push-11 {
    left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-push-10 {
    left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-push-9 {
    left: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-push-8 {
    left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-push-7 {
    left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-push-6 {
    left: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-push-5 {
    left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-push-4 {
    left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-push-3 {
    left: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-push-2 {
    left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-push-1 {
    left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-push-0 {
    left: auto;
  }
  .col-md-offset-12 {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-11 {
    margin-left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-10 {
    margin-left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-9 {
    margin-left: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-8 {
    margin-left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-7 {
    margin-left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-6 {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-5 {
    margin-left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-4 {
    margin-left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-3 {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-1 {
    margin-left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-0 {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width:1200px) {
  .col-lg-1,
  .col-lg-2,
  .col-lg-3,
  .col-lg-4,
  .col-lg-5,
  .col-lg-6,
  .col-lg-7,
  .col-lg-8,
  .col-lg-9,
  .col-lg-10,
  .col-lg-11,
  .col-lg-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-lg-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-lg-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-lg-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-12 {
    right: 100%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-11 {
    right: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-10 {
    right: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-9 {
    right: 75%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-8 {
    right: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-7 {
    right: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-6 {
    right: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-5 {
    right: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-4 {
    right: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-3 {
    right: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-2 {
    right: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-1 {
    right: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-0 {
    right: auto;
  }
  .col-lg-push-12 {
    left: 100%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-11 {
    left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-10 {
    left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-9 {
    left: 75%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-8 {
    left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-7 {
    left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-6 {
    left: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-5 {
    left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-4 {
    left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-3 {
    left: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-2 {
    left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-1 {
    left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-0 {
    left: auto;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-12 {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-11 {
    margin-left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-10 {
    margin-left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-9 {
    margin-left: 75%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-8 {
    margin-left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-7 {
    margin-left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-6 {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-5 {
    margin-left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-4 {
    margin-left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-3 {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-1 {
    margin-left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-0 {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/cc7ee97be0.js"></script>
<div class="backwrap gradient">
  <div class="back-shapes">
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-desktop floating" style="top:65.50308008213553%;left:12.239583333333334%;animation-delay:-1.95s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-desktop floating" style="top:7.8028747433264884%;left:5.260416666666667%;animation-delay:-1.6s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-desktop floating" style="top:14.476386036960985%;left:33.4375%;animation-delay:-1.1s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-desktop floating" style="top:39.73305954825462%;left:22.916666666666668%;animation-delay:-4.7s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-eraser floating" style="top:46.50924024640657%;left:64.0625%;animation-delay:-1.5s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-eraser floating" style="top:73.40862422997947%;left:37.708333333333336%;animation-delay:-0.7s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-eraser floating" style="top:34.496919917864474%;left:42.447916666666664%;animation-delay:-0.05s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-git-square floating" style="top:5.030800821355236%;left:17.1875%;animation-delay:-0.45s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-git-square floating" style="top:59.034907597535934%;left:36.458333333333336%;animation-delay:-4.5s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-git-square floating" style="top:8.521560574948666%;left:47.604166666666664%;animation-delay:-3.5s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-linux floating" style="top:40.24640657084189%;left:9.166666666666666%;animation-delay:-0.05s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-linux floating" style="top:76.28336755646818%;left:23.125%;animation-delay:-4.6s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-linux floating" style="top:21.971252566735114%;left:69.73958333333333%;animation-delay:-4.2s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-linux floating" style="top:21.86858316221766%;left:44.375%;animation-delay:-3.05s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-linux floating" style="top:25.15400410677618%;left:27.03125%;animation-delay:-2.7s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-linux floating" style="top:82.95687885010267%;left:51.71875%;animation-delay:-2.1s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-smile-o floating" style="top:68.17248459958932%;left:79.32291666666667%;animation-delay:-3.25s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-smile-o floating" style="top:15.40041067761807%;left:96.04166666666667%;animation-delay:-2.6s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-smile-o floating" style="top:11.396303901437372%;left:79.94791666666667%;animation-delay:-2.15s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-smile-o floating" style="top:10.574948665297741%;left:62.447916666666664%;animation-delay:-1.8s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-whatsapp floating" style="top:75.77002053388091%;left:31.145833333333332%;animation-delay:-3.95s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-whatsapp floating" style="top:27.82340862422998%;left:11.25%;animation-delay:-3.45s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-whatsapp floating" style="top:82.95687885010267%;left:3.9583333333333335%;animation-delay:-2.5s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-whatsapp floating" style="top:11.60164271047228%;left:29.635416666666668%;animation-delay:-2.05s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-whatsapp floating" style="top:26.078028747433265%;left:0.46875%;animation-delay:-1.5s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-whatsapp floating" style="top:49.07597535934291%;left:55.520833333333336%;animation-delay:-1.2s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-whatsapp floating" style="top:71.66324435318275%;left:49.114583333333336%;animation-delay:-0.95s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-whatsapp floating" style="top:41.37577002053388%;left:33.072916666666664%;animation-delay:-0.7s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-wifi floating" style="top:84.49691991786447%;left:19.166666666666668%;animation-delay:-1.65s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-wifi floating" style="top:44.558521560574945%;left:2.65625%;animation-delay:-1.15s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-wifi floating" style="top:51.74537987679671%;left:21.197916666666668%;animation-delay:-0.7s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-wifi floating" style="top:17.864476386036962%;left:57.65625%;animation-delay:-0.45s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-wifi floating" style="top:5.749486652977413%;left:34.583333333333336%;animation-delay:-0.15s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-wifi floating" style="top:66.0164271047228%;left:51.979166666666664%;animation-delay:-4.8s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-wifi floating" style="top:79.67145790554414%;left:76.61458333333333%;animation-delay:-4.5s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-wifi floating" style="top:39.52772073921971%;left:77.34375%;animation-delay:-4.25s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-wifi floating" style="top:29.363449691991786%;left:66.92708333333333%;animation-delay:-4.05s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-wifi floating" style="top:3.2854209445585214%;left:79.375%;animation-delay:-3.8s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-wifi floating" style="top:12.833675564681725%;left:51.666666666666664%;animation-delay:-3.55s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-wifi floating" style="top:34.90759753593429%;left:50.104166666666664%;animation-delay:-3.25s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-user floating" style="top:33.880903490759756%;left:17.552083333333332%;animation-delay:-1.65s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-user floating" style="top:20.32854209445585%;left:17.291666666666668%;animation-delay:-1.25s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-user floating" style="top:24.94866529774127%;left:42.291666666666664%;animation-delay:-0.85s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-user floating" style="top:28.33675564681725%;left:63.75%;animation-delay:-0.5s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-user floating" style="top:42.813141683778234%;left:61.197916666666664%;animation-delay:-0.2s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-user floating" style="top:62.62833675564682%;left:59.53125%;animation-delay:-4.95s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-user floating" style="top:71.66324435318275%;left:59.635416666666664%;animation-delay:-4.6s;"></em>
    <em class="active epic-icon fa fa-user floating" style="top:55.441478439425055%;left:39.84375%;animation-delay:-4.3s;"></em>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо большое